# How do I create a new column - R Language

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to change my tibble so that every observation gets paired with the following observation into a new row, while retaining the id.

```
x1 <- c("cook", "clean", "wash", "walk", "wish", "broom", "clean", "wash", "walk", "cook")
x2 <- c("move", "climb", "skate", "ball", "climb", "jog", "job", "skate", "ball", "climb")
x3 <- c("try", "clean", "boom", "walk", "bring", "broom", "sing", "wash", "jump", "fly")

df <- tibble(y, x1, x2, x3)
```

In this situation,

row 1 should be: y=1, x1="cook", x2="move"

row 2 should be: y=1, x2="move", x3="try"

row 3 should be: y=2, x1="clean",  x2="climb"

row 4 should be: y=2, x2="climb", x3="clean"

I tried the following:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to="obs", values_to="val", x1:x3) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = val, x2 = lead(val)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(x2)) %>% 
  select(y, x1, x2)
```

And get an error:

> `Can't combine y <integer> and x1 <character>`

Comment: `tibble(x1, x2, x3) %>%
  mutate(y = row_number()) %>% ` + your code starting with `pivot_longer` works for me.

Comment: gotcha ure right!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Please do not vandalize your questions. Then, anyone who has the same problem would have to look into the revisions to see the question. It has already been rolled back, but please don't do it in the future.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts.  By posting on this site, you've given the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so.  If you wish to delete your question, click the "Delete" button, it's next to "Follow" (note:  This isn't possible if your question's been answered).

Comment: @JonSpring, please post as answer?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. What is `y` in `df <- tibble(y, x1, x2, x3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't define `y`, but it looks like this is intended to use row number of the original data. We can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x1, x2, x3) %>% 
   mutate(y = row_number()) %>%

  # the rest from the original post
  pivot_longer(names_to="obs", values_to="val", x1:x3) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = val, x2 = lead(val)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(x2)) %>% 
  select(y, x1, x2)

# A tibble: 20 × 3
# Groups:   y [10]
       y x1    x2   
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 cook  move 
 2     1 move  try  
 3     2 clean climb
 4     2 climb clean
 5     3 wash  skate
 6     3 skate boom 
 7     4 walk  ball 
 8     4 ball  walk 
 9     5 wish  climb
10     5 climb bring
11     6 broom jog  
12     6 jog   broom
13     7 clean job  
14     7 job   sing 
15     8 wash  skate
16     8 skate wash 
17     9 walk  ball 
18     9 ball  jump 
19    10 cook  climb
20    10 climb fly
```

(P.S. we could throw an ol' ungroup() in there if we might be plotting or processing further and expect ungrouped data for that.)